# Can't downgread to W7 from W8 on a ASUS R503U

Tags: windows-7

I have trying to downgrade my ASUS R503U from W8 to W7 I have tried everything, and still can't do a fresh install of W7, I I'm not able to Enable the CSM and here is the problem, does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: activate VGA Option ROM loading. This caused the setup failure for my Dell Laptop. You can also keep Win8, install Aero glass (http://glass8.berlios.de/) and StartIsBack (http://startisback.com/) and no you have a better Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about Asus, but I would contact them. HP is rereleasing windows 7-64 computers because of all the complaints about windows 8. They have 4 lappies out and 1 desktop. They are also giving all that had windows 7 with opt to update to 8. The option now to downgrade back to 7. I've contacted Asus about a couple issues with my 7 ran on last line and they've been very nice about fixing the problems.